# error code 3021 either bof or eof is true or the current record has been deleted

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access 2003 database with some visual basic code using ADO calls in it. When I do a

```
strsql0 = "SELECT lnk_stockitm.C_C FROM lnk_stockitm WHERE (((lnk_stockitm.C_C) Like 'T*'));"
newRS.Open strsql0, cn1, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly  
newRS.movelast
```

I get this error:

> 3021 either bof or eof is true or the current record has been deleted

When I run the exact same query in the same function without the WHERE clause, like this:

```
strsql0 = "SELECT lnk_stockitm.C_C FROM lnk_stockitm;
```

I get the correct result of 56,000 records. If I paste the full SQL statement with the WHERE clause into a regular query, like so:

```
SELECT lnk_stockitm.C_C FROM lnk_stockitm WHERE (((lnk_stockitm.C_C) Like 'T*'));
```

it returns the correct subset of the results (2800 records).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wildcard difference is the cause for difference between what you execute from ADO and within your access database.  Convert your statement to use "%" rather than "*".  As a general rule of thumb, it may be a good idea to encapsulate your code by checking for eof before calling `MoveLast`.  If your query has zero results it'll bomb out every time.

```
strsql0 = "SELECT lnk_stockitm.C_C FROM lnk_stockitm WHERE (((lnk_stockitm.C_C) Like 'T*'));"
newRS.Open strsql0, cn1, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly  

if not newRs.eof then
   newRS.movelast
else
  ' do something here if necessary to handle blank results
end if
```

Comment: How embarrassing. I read about this a long time ago, and hadn't had a need to use it for so long I forgot.

Thanks for the heads up on checking for EOF first. I'm actually doing that already. I just chopped out all the code to get to the minimum case causing my error, to make it quick and easy for people to look at.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the '%' character as wildcard when using ADO.

[MSDN Article: Using the Right Wildcard Characters in SQL Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140104(office.10).aspx)