# ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd' Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record

Tags: sql, adodb

I keep getting this error and I am not sure how to fix it.  I am new to this and any help would be awesome. This is used on a website that I am working on for a project and this is the only error that I have encountered.

the error message is this:

> ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

> /asctutor/includes/header.asp, line 58

And the code  is below(I have highlighted line 58):

```vb
    '******************************************************
    '   Retrieve user's real full name
    '******************************************************

    Function getRealName (UserName)

    if UserName <> "EMPTY" then
    EstablishDBCON rstutor7courses, concourses

    sqlString = "Select * from Users where UserName ='"&UserName&"'"
    'Response.write sqlString
  rstutor7courses.open sqlString
 if rstutor7courses.eof=false then UserType =rstutor7courses("Type")end if 
   rstutor7courses.close 

 sqlString = "Select F_Name,L_Name from "&UserType&" where UserName ='"&UserName&"'"
    'Response.write sqlString
    rstutor7courses.open sqlString
    UserFName = rstutor7courses("F_Name") 
    UserLName = rstutor7courses("L_Name") 
    getRealName = UserFName & " " & UserLName
    rstutor7courses.close
    else
    getRealName = ""
    end if

    end function
```

so I have edited the code on line 58 but now I get this error:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
>   /asctutor/includes/header.asp, line 63

Comment: is it possible that your query is returning no records?

Comment: Search this site for "BOF or EOF is True" and review the several dozen questions that have already been asked (and answered) previously here. There are even a couple in the **Related** list to the right of the question you posted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error code 3021 either bof or eof is true or the current record has been deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712383/error-code-3021-either-bof-or-eof-is-true-or-the-current-record-has-been-deleted)