# vba - Run time error 3021 - EOF or BOF is true or the current record has been deleted

Tags: vba, oledb

I have written the bellow code, but i am getting an error at `getIDKategori = rs!id_kategori`

```
Public Function getIDKategori(ByVal nama As String) As Integer
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
  rs.Open "SELECT kategori.id_kategori FROM kategori WHERE nama_kategori='" & nama & "';"

  getIDKategori = rs!id_kategori
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Your select query is not returning any records.  You should test for EOF before trying to access results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error code 3021 either bof or eof is true or the current record has been deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712383/error-code-3021-either-bof-or-eof-is-true-or-the-current-record-has-been-deleted)